# Terraform Conditional depending if a resource has been created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created a compute module that has a conditional to create an external IP.

```
resource "google_compute_address" "external" {     
    count = "${var.EXT_IP_CREATE ? 1 : 0}"     
    name = "${var.NAME}-ext-ip"     
    address_type = "EXTERNAL"     
    region = "${var.REGION}"}
```

Within the compute instance resource block, I have the following network interface configuration:

```
network_interface {     
    network= "${var.NETWORK}"     
    network_ip = "${google_compute_address.internal.address}"         
    access_config {         
         nat_ip = "${var.EXT_IP_CREATE ? google_compute_address.external.address : 0 }"         
        }     
    }
```

If the resource google_compute_address.external has not been created, I need to set nat_ip to null or in other words 0.

That looks like it should work but it does not.

When setting EXT_IP_CREATE to true TF succeeds to create the resource. When setting it to false I receive the following error:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.compute-dbma-dev.google_compute_instance.compute: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.compute-dbma-dev.google_compute_instance.compute: Resource 'google_compute_address.external' not found for variable 'google_compute_address.external.address'
```

When I explicitly pass nat_ip = 0 TF recognizes the blank value and successfully creates the compute instances without the external IP.

Im currently on Terraform version Terraform v0.11. There is probably a super simple solution but I am just starting out with conditionals in TF and I getting stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So your intention to do an optional argument with `null` is not possible before 0.12, but your real problem here is you need to set it for all of the `network_interface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to fix that:

1. `TF_WARN_OUTPUT_ERRORS=1 terraform apply`
2. `${element(concat(google_compute_address.*.address, list("")), 0)}`

Comment: Neither 1 or 2 worked. For 1, I am still receiving the same resource not found for variable error. For 2, I am receiving this: Error: resource 'google_compute_instance.compute' config: unknown resource 'google_compute_address.*' referenced in variable google_compute_address.*.address

Comment: try: ${element(concat(google_compute_address.external.*.address, list("")), 0)}"

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use a similar conditional, I get the following error:

```
* google_compute_instance.main: __builtin_StringToInt: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax in:

${var.external_ip != "" ? var.external_ip : 0}
```

I do not see how the external IP can be conditionally attached, based on how GCP API works currently [1]:

```
networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP => string

An external IP address associated with this instance. Specify an unused static external IP address available to the project or leave this field undefined to use an IP from a shared ephemeral IP address pool. If you specify a static external IP address, it must live in the same region as the zone of the instance.
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances